# scanning numbers into string in c

Tags: c, tolower

I have a list of words lets say:

```
Hello
FAR
DC2012
```

I need to scan all of these as strings and put them into a binary tree. Except whenever I scan , my program fails at the third string "DC2012". I'm guessing it is because it has numbers and I'm using the "tolower" function but I need to use it so I am not sure. Here is my code for scanning:

```
while (fscanf(afp, "%s ", words) != NULL) {

            for(i=0; words[i]!='\0'; i++){
                words[i]=(char)tolower(words[i]);
            }
            printf("%s\n", words);
```

Comment: Your guess is wrong: when a character is not an uppercase letter, `tolower` returns it back unchanged.

Comment: `program fails`. How exactly does it fail?

Comment: I don't really know since I'm using visual studio, but it stops printing after the second word so i thought it either has to do with scanning in numbers as a string or using the tolower function on the numbers.

Comment: how did you define `words`? What exactly is the error message?

Comment: defined: char words[1000];
Visual studio makes a break and takes me to the "setlocal.h" and says somethings wrong with the " ptd = _getptd();" Don't know what any of this is and it won't let me go on any further.

Answer (score 1):

It does an infinite loop, use `fgets()` instead of `scanf`. And you don't need to cast the return of `tolower()`.